# Wordpress menu button send to page

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

I need to make a site for a friend of me in WordPress.
Maybe you can help me with this thing.
my problem is that I need to make a menu with a few pages inside, what I did correctly.
Now is the part coming what my question concerns.
I need to make a page which sends you directly to a website. How do I do this?
Do I need to make a code inside the page?
Do I need to make a code inside the menu or something?
I don't know how or what to do. So I didn't try anything, because I don't know how.

Thank you in advance, 
Banana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly set external website link using add link into menu. This configuration available in wordpress backendside.
Go to : appearance -> menus -> links

Comment: You sir, you are a hero!